# Not able to add any additional attribute to Magento 2 Custom Theme's Logo Element

Tags: magento2, theme, custom, parent-child-theme, logo

I have successfully created a custom theme as a child of Luma theme in my Magento CE 2.0.12 installation.

But if I add below code in my `layout/theme.xml` file, I am not able to add a `title` attribute to `img` tag of Logo:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
           <arguments>
              <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/mytheme_logo.svg</argument>
              <argument name="logo_alt" xsi:type="string">Custom Alt</argument>
              <argument name="logo_title" xsi:type="string">Custom's Logo</argument>
              <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
              <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
           </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Please suggest how to add additional attribute to `img` tag of Logo.

Comment: Hello Vicky, Changing via admin can not be an option?

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't work with custom theme.

Comment: This question needs to be upvoted so that it can get much attention, this could help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override template of **logo.phtml** into your custom theme.

Follow below steps :

1. Assuming you have already created custom theme and its working fine and activated !! (**Location is : app/design/frontend/VendorName/themename**)
2. Create one folder in the your custom theme directory name **Magento_Theme**
3. Now create **logo.phtml** file in "**Magento_theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml**" on this location.
4. Copy your default **logo.phtml** file from theme and paste its content into your custom **logo.phtml** file. Add title attribute to that image tag.

**logo.phtml code should be like below :**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo $block
 */
?>
<?php $storeName = $block->getThemeName() ? $block->getThemeName() : $block->getLogoAlt();?>
<span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Toggle Nav') ?></span></span>
<?php if ($block->isHomePage()):?>
    <strong class="logo">
<?php else: ?>
    <a class="logo" href="<?php echo $block->getUrl(''); ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $storeName ?>">
<?php endif ?>
        <img src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLogoSrc() ?>"
             alt="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLogoAlt() ?>"
             <?php echo $block->getLogoWidth() ? 'width="' . $block->getLogoWidth() . '"' : '' ?>
             <?php echo $block->getLogoHeight() ? 'height="' . $block->getLogoHeight() . '"' : '' ?>
       title="TESTESTESTEST" />
<?php if ($block->isHomePage()):?>
    </strong>
<?php else:?>
    </a>
<?php endif?>
```

Here i have added **title="TESTESTESTEST"** it shows on the logo image. Clear the cache and check

Comment: @VickyDev Thank you !! Happy to help , Keep helping :)